# GCP API methods: empty request body vs {}?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform

Some GCP API methods require an empty request body, others require {} in the body.  I can't figure out any pattern.

Examples of methods that require an empty request body, and return an error if called with {}:

- https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/getIamPolicy
- https://cloud.google.com/iam/reference/rest/v1/roles/list

Examples of methods that require {} in the body, and return an error if called with an empty body:

- https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects/getIamPolicy
- https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.topics/create

Confusingly, all four of these docs say that the request body must be empty!  For the second group, I'd say that's a bug: the body must be *non-empty*; it must be {}.

This is pretty annoying - it feels like random difference peppered across the methods?  Is there any rhyme or reason here?  Couldn't the body {} methods accept an empty body?

Some ideas that don't seem to explain the difference:

- Since many products use IAM, those functions could have quirky behavior.  But see above - `getIamPolicy` is different between products.
- Different product teams could decide on different local conventions.    But see above - the pubsub API has calls in each camp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first two links that you shared are HTTP `GET` methods, which should not have a body, as it should only retrieve data, and all the information can be passed through the URL and some query parameters.

The other two links are HTTP `PUT` methods, which expect a payload to update the current content of a given entity.

You can find more explanation about how the HTTP methods are defined in the [IETF RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9), explaining the HTTP protocol.

Comment: Aha, thanks!  google-api-python-client doesn't make the method obvious, didn't even think about that difference.